How to include printed response(s) from mock server back into karate.HTML report
I was wondering if its possible to include the interactions with a given mock server(s) printed request(incoming) and response (outgoing) back into the finished native karate.html report?
Ive had a bit of a play but I havent been able to incorporate back into the report. I can print it and visually see it on the console output but cant integrate to report.
Is this possible?
Cheers
JB
p.s. I hope all is going well :)

It is possible to get the Logger instance that Karate uses for reporting from a ThreadLocal like this:
private static com.intuit.karate.Logger logger() {
    ScenarioEngine engine = ScenarioEngine.get();
    return engine.logger;
}

Then using this Logger can contribute to the HTML report.
However, this may be tricky with a mock, because a mock internally needs another instance of a ScenarioEngine, and there is some hacking behind the scenes to swap the ThreadLocal. This may be improved in the future after switching the JS engine.
Also I have to caution you that this API can change in future. I don't think it will change more than a package change to io.karatelabs - but still, no guarantees.
